# pip3 is not installed with the latest python3 via Homebrew (macOS)

Tags: macos, python, homebrew, pip

`pip3` disappeared after the latest Homebrew `python3` update.

```
user:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
user:~$ pip3 --version
-bash: pip3: command not found
```

Homebrew claims that it installed the symlinks for `pip3` but they are not there:

```
user:~$ brew info python
python: stable 3.7.3 (bottled), HEAD
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3 (8,115 files, 114.3MB) *
  Built from source on 2019-04-02 at 15:12:30
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/python.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
Required: gdbm ✔, openssl ✔, readline ✔, sqlite ✔, xz ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
Python has been installed as
  /usr/local/bin/python3

Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
  /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin

If you need Homebrew's Python 2.7 run
  brew install python@2

You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages

See: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python
==> Analytics
install: 506,030 (30 days), 1,433,297 (90 days), 3,912,271 (365 days)
install_on_request: 248,801 (30 days), 764,732 (90 days), 2,361,156 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)

user:~$ ll /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin
total 0
0 drwxr-xr-x  6 user  admin  192 Apr  2 15:12 .
0 drwxr-xr-x  6 user  admin  192 Apr  2 15:12 ..
0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  admin   58 Apr  2 15:12 idle -> ../../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/idle3.7
0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  admin   59 Apr  2 15:12 pydoc -> ../../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pydoc3.7
0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  admin   60 Apr  2 15:12 python -> ../../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  admin   68 Apr  2 15:12 python-config -> ../../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7m-config

user:~$ ll /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/
total 104
 0 drwxr-xr-x  16 user  staff    512 Apr  2 16:16 .
 0 drwxr-xr-x   9 user  staff    288 Mar 25 14:59 ..
 0 lrwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff      8 Mar 25 14:59 2to3 -> 2to3-3.7
 8 -rwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff    162 Apr  2 16:16 2to3-3.7
 0 lrwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff      7 Mar 25 14:59 idle3 -> idle3.7
 8 -rwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff    160 Apr  2 16:16 idle3.7
 0 lrwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff      8 Mar 25 14:59 pydoc3 -> pydoc3.7
 8 -rwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff    145 Apr  2 16:16 pydoc3.7
 0 lrwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff      9 Mar 25 14:59 python3 -> python3.7
 0 lrwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff     16 Mar 25 14:59 python3-config -> python3.7-config
32 -rwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff  13620 Apr  2 16:16 python3.7
 0 lrwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff     17 Mar 25 14:59 python3.7-config -> python3.7m-config
32 -rwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff  13620 Apr  2 16:16 python3.7m
 8 -rwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff   2103 Apr  2 16:16 python3.7m-config
 0 lrwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff     10 Mar 25 14:59 pyvenv -> pyvenv-3.7
 8 -rwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff    502 Apr  2 16:16 pyvenv-3.7
```

`brew cleanup` and `brew reinstall python` do not work. I am also using `pyenv` and I wonder if this could create any problems. Right now I have uninstalled all `python` versions from `pyenv` and reinstalled the latest Homewbrew one, still no success.

P.S. I am aware of `python3 -m pip` command but am looking for a way to restore the standard `pip3` calls.

Comment: Does brew doctor output anything?

Comment: `brew doctor` doesn't show anything related to python. I fixed all the broken symlinks just in case, still no `pip3` in the system.